# Why might .save fail silently while running a custom rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub, rake-task

I am writing a rake task that alters every record in a model called `Update`.  For some reason, the record is not being saved to the database even though `save` (or `save!`) returns `true`.

I'm testing it just using one record (`Update.last`) to try and pin down the problem.  So I take a record using `u = Update.last`, modify it, and then use `binding.pry` to try and figure out what is happening.

This is the behaviour I have in `pry`:

```
pry(main)> Update.last
=> #<Update id: 598, ..., interesting_attribute: "old text">
pry(main)> u
=> #<Update id: 598, ..., interesting_attribute: "new text">
pry(main)> u.save
=> true
pry(main)> u.save!
=> true
pry(main)> Update.last
=> #<Update id: 598, ..., interesting_attribute: "old text">
pry(main)> u
=> #<Update id: 598, ..., interesting_attribute: "new text">
```

I don't understand why `Update.last` is not being updated after `save` has reported success.  Why is that?

EDIT:

The attribute itself is changed using:

```
u.interesting_attribute.gsub! 'old', 'new'
```

Comment: It's not changed in the console, but is it changed in the database? What does: Update.find(598) returns?

Comment: No, it hasn't changed in the database.  `Update.find(598)` returns the same thing as `Update.last` (i.e. the unmodified version).

Comment: how do you change the attribute? I think we'll need to see more code. Some `before_save` callbacks might be at fault.

Comment: I've added the line that changes the attribute above.  I don't have any `before_save`s in the `Update` model.

Comment: Don't use `gsub!`, `interesting_attribute` is a method. You're just changing the returned value. Try assigning: `u.interesting_attribute = u.interesting_attribute.gsub 'old', 'new'`. Where are you making this change, in a `before_save`?

Comment: Magic, that's got it (even if I'm not 100% sure I understand it).  I'm making this change in a custom rake task that will run through all the `Update`s.

Comment: If you need to batch update a lot of these, it would be easier to leverage SQL to handle the whole thing -- `Update.where(interesting_attribute: 'old').update_all(interesting_attribute: 'new')` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use bang methods like gsub! to change attributes of a Rails object.**

`interesting_attribute` is a method. `gsub!` is just changing the returned value, not altering the attribute. Try assigning instead:

```
u.interesting_attribute = u.interesting_attribute.gsub 'old', 'new'
```

(Thanks to Satya for this answer, posted as a comment.)